# fetch post body to express breaks request body value into smaller key values

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

i'm trying to post a url to express and grab the the url in express from the body but it splits the url string in to different key values.  what am i doing wrong? i need the string to be completed in express.

My Fetch Post:

```
const bodyContent = JSON.stringify({
    url: "https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Womens-Ultraboost-Running-Metallic/dp/B07RFNL3PW/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=adidas+ultraboost&pd_rd_r=c074b464-277c-4efb-bd29-86461b54835a&pd_rd_w=7QuQt&pd_rd_wg=VWKbv&pf_rd_p=0f7345d0-8152-4ac5-802c-50e10d235750&pf_rd_r=VG0MZMGVV1AP1WVX8B5G&qid=1647451696&refinements=p_89%3AStella+McCartney%7Cadidas%7Cadidas+Originals&s=apparel&sr=1-8&wi=us-slds-sp-2-t1-a2_3"
})
fetch('http://localhost:8888/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: bodyContent,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
}).then(resp => console.log(resp)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

My Express setup:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send(req.body)
})
```

Result:

```
{
  '{"url":"https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Womens-Ultraboost-Running- 
  Metallic/dp/B07RFNL3PW/ref': 'sr_1_8?keywords=adidas ultraboost',
  pd_rd_r: 'c074b464-277c-4efb-bd29-86461b54835a',
  pd_rd_w: '7QuQt',
  pd_rd_wg: 'VWKbv',
  pf_rd_p: '0f7345d0-8152-4ac5-802c-50e10d235750',
  pf_rd_r: 'VG0MZMGVV1AP1WVX8B5G',
  qid: '1647451696',
  refinements: 'p_89:Stella McCartney|adidas|adidas Originals',
  s: 'apparel',
  sr: '1-8',
  wi: 'us-slds-sp-2-t1-a2_3"}'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Change this on the front-end:

- "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- "Content-Type": "application/json"

It is converting the = in the url to individual key-value pairs.

You are using a json anyway for the body, so this should work.

Comment: tried that but it comes back with an empty req.body

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but this line is looking suspicious.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Probably you don't want `extended: true`. Try setting it to false.

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded